# Is there a way to slide one big "slide" using swiper.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I'm trying to find a way to slide my data within a container without having to use the default horizotal scrollbar.

So I tried using [swiper.js](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/). It works - kind of, but the problem is that I can't freely slide it back and forth without the "slide" automatically sliding back.

[I made a fiddle here to test](https://jsfiddle.net/t16jptws/1/).

Here is the JS code I'm using:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    freeMode: true,
    freeModeSticky: false,
    grabCursor: true
  });
```

Is it possible using swipe.js to freely moving the content back and fort?
If no, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Something like this Steven? https://jsfiddle.net/t16jptws/2/ . The problem seems to be that the class `swiper-slide` is missing, and I've tried but i can't make it work on a table.

Comment: Lets me know if it worked for you

Comment: Yes, exactly like that @CarstenLøvboAndersen! Only that I was thinking of using 1 big slide as I want to output a table - hence my question title ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you only have one slide with the table. I edited your fiddle to add a `<div class="swiper-slide"></div>` before the table slide and it stopped resetting back to the start.